# Java BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста... как с помощью BigDecimal сформировать и сохранить сумму 123.00, если передали ее как 123?

Каких-либо похожих форматеров не нашел, буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Вы потом выводите данное поле в String?

Comment: Да, там для этих целей предусмотрен форматер  'public static String toString(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {

        DecimalFormat numFormat;
        String number;

        numFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");
        number = numFormat.format(bigDecimal);
        return number;
    }', проблема в том, что клиент может присылать суммы без значений после **.**, а на стороне сервера формируется цифровая подпись с учетом сумм

Comment: Так вы сами только что написали, как решить ваш вопрос. В чем тогда вопрос?) Вам нужно обязательно чтобы были пара нулей в конце или нет?

Comment: Точно!)), а использовал String.valueOf.... Спасибо!))

Comment: Не за что) Сами задали вопрос, сами ответили. Чудеса автоматизации

Comment: Оформите ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: Ответ готов) как пометить не знаю)

Comment: @alan, когда вы сами отвечаете на свой вопрос, то отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа вы сможете только через 2 суток.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всем спасибо. Решено. Для сохранения в формате String, подходит форматер:

```
 public static String toString(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {

        DecimalFormat numFormat;
        String number;

        numFormat = new DecimalFormat(".00");
        number = numFormat.format(bigDecimal);
        return number;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
new BigDecimal("123.00").setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Comment: Вероятно хотели написать `new BigDecimal("123").setScale...`

Comment: @Sergey ты прав. так и хотел